# Windows Update Fails to install updates

Tags: windows, windows-update, wsus

Windows update fails to install the updates below.  How do I fix this, I've installed the fix it application Microsoft recommends but it still fails.  Any ideas how to fix this?

- Update for Microsoft Outlook Social Connector 2010 (KB2553406) 32-Bit Edition
- Update for Microsoft OneNote 2010 (KB2553290) 32-Bit Edition
- Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553310) 32-Bit Edition
- Windows Internet Explorer 9 for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems
- Update for Microsoft Outlook 2010 (KB2553248) 32-Bit Edition

I've also attached the windows update log if that helps. The machine is a Windows 7 and we run a windows 2008 SBS domain.

Comment: Don't see alog.  Are there any specific errors related to the failed updates?  Specific error codes?  Have you tried a manual install?

Comment: Reboot, Make sure you have all applications closed, and try updates again.

Comment: I just want people to tell Microsoft that they simply cannot provide a system that provides updates dependably. They simply cannot do it. I challenge them to do it. They will never be able to do it. This is something Windows users need to know. Microsoft has never provided a dependable updating system or method. They are incapable of it. It profits them, because people end up having to buy a new computer. And since Microsoft pretty much dominates this entire field, Microsoft profits from having lousy products and systems. That is my opinion, and I wish Microsoft would somehow prove me wrong. B

Answer (score 1):

Install them one-at-a-time, starting with the oldest (lowest numbered).  You've probably encountered a conflict between them that requires they be applied separately.

Comment: Tried one at a time and it failed after each one.

Comment: can i attach the windowsupdate logs on this forum?

Comment: @resolver101 yes you can.